# something similar to sql left join in php

Tags: php, arrays, left-join

I want sql left join functionality in php.

```
$table1 = array(
    0 => array("id" => "id1", "common_key" => 1),
    1 => array("id" => "id2", "common_key" => 2),
    2 => array("id" => "id3", "common_key" => 1)
);

$table2 = array(
    0 => array("name" => "name1", "common_key" => 1),
    1 => array("name" => "name2", "common_key" => 2)
);

$result = left_join($table1, $table2);
```

$result should be equal to array below.

```
array(
    0 => array("id" => "id1", "common_key" => 1, "name" => "name1"),
    1 => array("id" => "id2", "common_key" => 2, "name" => "name2"),
    2 => array("id" => "id3", "common_key" => 1, "name" => "name1")
)
```

What should be the left_join function?

Comment: Shouldn't `name` of this array be empty then? `2 => array("id" => "id3", "common_key" => 1, "name" => "name1")`

Comment: no. It should be same as mysql jeft join

Comment: Does PHPLinq (https://phplinq.codeplex.com/) are any of the similar libraries such as plinq (https://plinq.codeplex.com/) or linqforphp (https://linqforphp.codeplex.com/) give you what you need?

Comment: @ghost they're being joined on the `common_key` and all rows in `$table1` have a corresponding row in `$table2` for that column.

Comment: @Mark Baker no. I don't want to use a library. I just want a simple php code which will do the above task.

Comment: @salathe oh right, I missed it. Sorry.

Comment: @DamithK - If you don't want to use a library (why not?) then you're limited to writing the code yourself; so show use what you've tried otherwise your question is simply a `give me the codez` question

Comment: I'd probably stick the data into a database (SQLite in-memory is trivial with PDO) and *actually do a left join*. But that's just me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$table1 = array(
    0 => array("id" => "id1", "common_key" => 1),
    1 => array("id" => "id2", "common_key" => 2),
    2 => array("id" => "id3", "common_key" => 1)
);

$table2 = array(
    0 => array("name" => "name1", "common_key" => 1),
    1 => array("name" => "name2", "common_key" => 2)
);

$result = left_join($table1, $table2);
var_dump($result);

function left_join($table1, $table2) {
    array_walk(
        $table1,
        function(&$entry, $key, $joinTable) {
            foreach($joinTable as $joinKey => $joinValue) {
                if ($joinValue["common_key"] == $entry["common_key"]) {
                    $entry = array_merge($entry, $joinValue);
                    break;
                }
            }
        },
        $table2
    );
    return $table1;
}
```